# Query XML in SQL Server with sub tags in one row

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm new to XML and I am asked to write a T-SQL Query that will use an XML file and convert the same into a table/view with SQL Server. While the actual XML is a client data, I have attempted to simplify the XML file into below example.

I think the idea is similar to subquery but for XML and that I will display all steps for each case in a single row only.

```
 <testcases>
  <testcase>
    <testcasename> first </testcasename>
    <MediaType> Voice </MediaType>
    <steps>
      <CallSteps>
        <Step>
          <StepNo>1</StepNo>
          <description> first step </description>
          <StepNo>2</StepNo>
          <description> second step </description>
        </Step>
      </CallSteps>
    </steps>
  </testcase>
  <testcase>
    <testcasename> second </testcasename>
    <MediaType> Chat </MediaType>
    <steps>
      <CallSteps>
        <Step>
          <StepNo>1</StepNo>
          <description> first step </description>
          <StepNo>2</StepNo>
          <description> second step </description>
          <StepNo>3</StepNo>
          <description> Third step </description>
        </Step>
      </CallSteps>
    </steps>
  </testcase>
  <testcase>
    <testcasename> Third </testcasename>
    <MediaType> Voice </MediaType>
    <steps>
      <CallSteps>
        <Step>
          <StepNo>1</StepNo>
          <description> first step </description>
        </Step>
      </CallSteps>
    </steps>
  </testcase>
</testcases>
```

I want to display in below table

[image]

The number of step can go as many as possible (~100)

So far, I have come here -

```
    select @xml
declare @idoc int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xml; 
select *  from openxml(@idoc, '/testcases/testcase',2)
with (
testcasename nvarchar(10),
MediaType nvarchar(10),
steps  xml
)
```

Which gives below output

[image]

Please help

Comment: Don't use that *really*  old method. XQUERY has been around since at least SQL Server 2008 (possibly even 2005).

Comment: XQuery is available starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using that *really* old method of reading XML; it is really only still in SQL Server for back compatibility reasons. Instead use the "newer" (It still been around for at least 12 years) method of using XQUERY.

If you use a couple of `nodes` references, you can then get the actual values using the `value` function:

```sql
DECLARE @XML xml = '<testcases>
  <testcase>
    <testcasename> first </testcasename>
    <MediaType> Voice </MediaType>
    <steps>
      <CallSteps>
        <Step>
          <StepNo>1</StepNo>
          <description> first step </description>
          <StepNo>2</StepNo>
          <description> second step </description>
        </Step>
      </CallSteps>
    </steps>
  </testcase>
  <testcase>
    <testcasename> second </testcasename>
    <MediaType> Chat </MediaType>
    <steps>
      <CallSteps>
        <Step>
          <StepNo>1</StepNo>
          <description> first step </description>
          <StepNo>2</StepNo>
          <description> second step </description>
          <StepNo>3</StepNo>
          <description> Third step </description>
        </Step>
      </CallSteps>
    </steps>
  </testcase>
  <testcase>
    <testcasename> Third </testcasename>
    <MediaType> Voice </MediaType>
    <steps>
      <CallSteps>
        <Step>
          <StepNo>1</StepNo>
          <description> first step </description>
        </Step>
      </CallSteps>
    </steps>
  </testcase>
</testcases>';

SELECT tcs.tc.value('(testcasename/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS testcasename,
       tcs.tc.value('(MediaType/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS MediaType,
       CS.S.value('(StepNo/text())[1]','int') AS StepNo1,
       CS.S.value('(StepNo/text())[2]','int') AS StepNo2,
       CS.S.value('(StepNo/text())[3]','int') AS StepNo3,
       CS.S.value('(description/text())[1]','varchar(20)') AS description1,
       CS.S.value('(description/text())[2]','varchar(20)') AS description2,
       CS.S.value('(description/text())[3]','varchar(20)') AS description3
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
     CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/testcases/testcase')tcs(tc)
     CROSS APPLY tcs.tc.nodes('./steps/CallSteps/Step')CS(S);
```

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it however, Like I said, the number of steps can go as many as 100. Is there a way to dynamically expand CS.S.Value based on the XML that is getting passed?

Comment: If you need a dynamic number of columns, you would need dynamic SQL, @ShamvilKazmi . I would instead therefore suggest treating the data in a normalised form and having 1 row per step, not 1 column. Otherwise, if you must have columns, and not dynamic SQL, you'll need to write out all 100 (x2) references.

Comment: You are right about normalizing the data I will try to convince my client for this. If they don't agree, I will try to write with dynamic SQL and if I get stuck then will ask in a separate question in terms of this XML example.

I am really thankful for your help Larnu